# How to generate SPARC HW traps (trap type tt < 128)

Tags: exception, instructions, sparc

I'm programming a SPARC v8 (32bit) system and need to verify response to HW traps.

The SPARC provides 256 traps, each of which differing by the *trap type, tt*, of which the first 128 are the HW traps, and trap types 128 to 255 are *software traps*. The SPARC instruction set documents say that executing

```
ta N    ; trap always, n = 0..127
```

causes a trap of type tt=N+128. A trap causes a jump to the trap base address + tt * 16.

Is there a way to programmatically cause a HW trap *without* writing code exhibiting each of the HW trap conditions, such as window underflow, unaligned access, etc?

I'm thinking of installing SW trap handlers that simply jump to the handler for trap(N-128) and keep my fingers crossed. I'm uncomfortable with this idea because HW traps might cause other processor state to change which a SW trap wouldn't...

Comment: In general no, but your specific implementation of Sparc v8 may have a debug interface that allows testing hardware faults contact the vendor if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to programmatically cause a HW trap without writing
>   code exhibiting each of the HW trap conditions, such as window
>   underflow, unaligned access, etc?

No, there isn't a way to replicate all the effects caused by a hardware trap programmatically. For example, a real hardare trap sets the tt (trap type field) in the TBR register to indicate the type of the trap. This field cannot be modified by the programmer by writing to the TBR register. If this field is being read inside the trap handlers (for whatever reasons), you may not be able to set it artificially. However, as the comment mentions it may be possible to cause a hardware trap if your processor implementation provides a debug interface.

> I'm programming a SPARC v8 (32bit) system and need to verify response
>   to HW traps.

Is there a particular reason why you cannot write code which actually causes a hardware trap (for example a window overflow or divide by zero etc. ? It is actually quite straightforward to write small unit tests in sparc-asm for testing such traps. If you want to test the response to traps thoroughly it might actually be necessary. Another possiblity is to use a sparc V8 simulator.

Comment: My particular reason was that I in fact do write code causing each trap type, but for some it's quite involved; the implementation in question is the LEON3. I thought maybe I was missing something that would simplify my code.